# Retornar int em um select utilizando Dapper.

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Preciso retornar o idCidade. Se ele não encontrar em uma tabela, esta obrigatoriamente na outra.
O retorno é nulo.

**Minha Query**

```
public const string sql = @"DECLARE @retorno AS INT = 0;
                            SELECT @retorno = id 
                            FROM tabCidade1
                            WHERE nomeCidade = 'Curitiba'

                            SELECT @retorno = id
                            FROM tabCidade2
                            WHERE nomeCidade = 'Curitiba'

                            SELECT @retorno;";
```

**Código no c#**

```
using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    int idCidade = connection.Query<int>(sql);       
}
```

Comment: Não podia ser algo mais simples, como TOP 1 + UNION, OU UNION ALL?

Comment: Qual o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando o .Single() no seu comando

```
using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    int idCidade = connection.Query<int>(sql).Single();       
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]